# Query for mapping configuration from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My scenario is this:
Table A is the keys (map) of configuration values for different systems. I am creating a config panel, and in the query for TableA, the results will be filtered by SystemName.

My problem is that I am unable to get the result with empty/null/values as shown in result. This is required because UI is rendering the labels and text boxes based on this result.

TableB may or may not have values for all the keys in config map.

I want the values in this format (that is first get all the values from TableA and then fill the values from TableB and return the result):

```
TableA
ID Name  SystemName
1  Path1 SystemA
2  Path2 SystemA
3  Path3 SystemA
4  Path1 SystemB
5  Path2 SystemB
6  Path3 SystemB


TableB
ID TableAID Value
1  2        //Volumes/SomeDrive/SomeFolder

Result
ID Name   TableAID SystemName Value
1  Path1  1        SystemA    ''
2  Path2  2        SystemA    //Volumes/SomeDrive/SomeFolder
3  Path3  3        SystemA    ''
```

Is there an easy solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(TableB.ID, TableA.ID) AS ID,
    TableA.Name, 
    TableA.ID as TableAID, 
    TableA.SystemName, 
    ISNULL(TableB.Value,'') AS Value
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you use an Outer join instead of an inner.

Comment: Why the down vote?  This was the solution as the selected answer proves this.